# Managing multiple stylesheets in Blazor

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor, radzen

## Managing multiple stylesheets in Blazor

### Background

- I am a backend developer creating a Blazor WASM website.

### Problem

- I am currently developing an application which is using MudBlazor. I am happy with MudBlazor and would like to continue to use it.
- However, I would also like to use the HTML editor provided by Radzen.
- The issue I am facing is that there are elements in the MudBlazor sytlesheet (I'm not sure exactly which ones) which are keeping the visuals in the Radzen HTML Editor from working at 100% (bullet points not appearing, indentation not quite right, etc).

[With Mudblazor stylesheet active, the text editor does not work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9cWb.png)

### What I've Tried

- To confirm that the issue is with the MudBlazor stylesheet, I have commented out the MudBlazor stylesheet in index.html, resulting in the html editor working as expected (but the rest of the website not having the MudBlazor styles). The image below shows the result:
  [With MudBlazor stylesheet commented, the text editor works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkAiI.png)
- I have put the Radzen Text editor into its own component, so that there are no MudBlazor components accompanying it. From there, I have been attempting to find a way of excluding the mudblazor stylesheet from the html editor component.

  - Investigated the use of Blazor CSS Isolation, but from what I can see this is designed for the use of custom css created by myself, not the use of stylesheets (please correct me if I'm wrong).
  - I read somewhere that in general html the latest stylesheet will be utilised. So, in my TextEditor.razor page, add the stylesheet in an attempt to make it the last thing read:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css" >
</head>
```

### The Code:

#### Index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Writers Friend Web App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!-- Commenting the below stylesheet allows the Text Editor to work as expected -->
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor.ThemeManager/MudBlazorThemeManager.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

#### TextEditor.razor

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css" >
</head>
<RadzenHtmlEditor Style="min-height: 300px; margin: 1rem;"/>

@code 
{
    [Parameter]
    public Action<string> OnTextChange { get; set; }
}
```

### What I'm looking for

- I would like a way of allowing the Text Editor component to have access to the text editor stylesheet ONLY. i.e. exclude the MudBlazor stylesheet from my component.
- I'm wondering if I can remove the MudBlazor stylesheet from the index.html file and include it in the  section of all the other components, but this would make it messy and I would like to avoid this if possible.

### Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is the correct way to [control `<head>` content in a Razor component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-7.0#control-head-content-in-a-razor-component). Not sure if it will fix your issue but you should change `TextEditor.razor` to use `HeadContent` instead of plain `<head>` html tag.